# Is $X$ connected if for every continuous $ f $, $ f(X)$ is an interval

Tags: general-topology

Given a metric space $X$, and for every continuous $f: X \to \mathbb{R}$ , $f(X)$ is an interval, do we have the connectedness for X?

I am trying to provide a counter example, but I cannot find any. So I guess this is true. How do I prove this? Should I prove this by contradiction?

**Note:** The original version of this question asked whether $X$ must be connected under the assumption that $f(X)$ is connected for *some* continuous function $f:X \to \mathbb{R}$ (rather than all such functions), hence some of the answers and comments.

Comment: Consider $X=(-2,-1) \cup (1,2)$ and $f:x \mapsto x^2$.

Comment: At the extreme end of failure, the Cantor Staircase Function surjects the Cantor set (whose components are all of its single points) onto the interval $[0,1]$. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function

Comment: @DHMO, this is the emptyset, so f is the empty map. Did you mean union?

Comment: Sorry, I meant union. Fixed.

Comment: @user335468 have you proven that the connected subsets of the reals are intervals?

Comment: I am sorry, I mean for every continuous function f

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is false. Any constant function $f:X\to\{a\}$ is continuous and its image is connected. But $X$ could be "anything".

EDIT

Your second statement is true. If $X$ is not connected, write $X=A\cup B$ for nonempty open and disjoint sets $A$ and $B$. Now define $f(x)=0$ for $x\in A$ and $f(x)=1$ for $x\in B$.

Comment: I guess this depends on what OP meant by "interval" i.e. did he mean nondegenerate

Comment: What if I change a condition, for every continuous function $f: X \to \mathbb{R}$, $f(X)$ is an interval? I believe this is true?

Comment: @user335468: Sure, if $X$ is disconnected, then it has a partition $X= U \cup V$ into nonempty open sets. The function taking the value $0$ on $U$ and the value $1$ on $V$ is continuous, with image not an interval.

Comment: Oh! I've never thought of using contrapositive!

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $X$ has a separation $A,B$. In this case the function $f : X \to \mathbb R$ given by $f(x) = 1$ if $x \in A$ and $f(x) = 0$ if $x \in B$ is continuous.

This means that if $X$ is not connected, there exists a continuous function $f : X \to \mathbb R$ with the property that $f(X)$ is not an interval.

Consider the contrapositive.